# Cross domain Frame communication

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

We have 2 web application that display there information in 2 different frames (A & B). The javascript in A read the hidden fields of B and take some actions based on the values of the  hidden fields. Also A is responsible to load the first page of B, B can have more than one page and command for A can be in any pages of B, The pages of B a are construct dynamically base on the current state of B
Everything work fine when A and B come from the same domain.
But in some case (Performance and Architeture of the application) we need to have A and B to come from 2 differents domain and in this case the Cross domain restriction do not allow A to read the B hidden field. I try tho use Access-Control-Allow-Origin but it seams do not work between 2 frames already loaded in the browser.
Although you can think that is a security problem can be raise with this kind of applications, these application are designed to run on an intranet.

Do someones has an idea for resolving the problem

Frank

Comment: dont have 100% solution but...using two iframe's from domain A one to post and the other to display would solve this. also script tags are used to overcome cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

In situations where you have multiple iframes from different domains within the same window -- you should be using the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) which enables sending messages between iframes (regardless of origin). However, you will have to change the code in both iframes to get postMessage to work.

Basically, instead of A reading fields of B, A would send a message to B to tell that it wants to read it's fields, and then B would send another message back to A with the data in those fields.

You could also try using some more advanced libraries based on postmessage such as [jsChannel](https://github.com/mozilla/jschannel) and [pmrpc](https://github.com/izuzak/pmrpc) which enable you to communicate between iframes in a more natural way (remote procedure call) instead of sending messages.